# How to execute a script on all subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a domain with subdomains witch are used by bunch of people... The thing is that I can't understand wich subdomains are in use by the right people. So my question is:
How to execute a javascript alert with a message(in all subdomains) to users to send me a email if subdomain is in use...
Sorry for my bad English and bad explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use (in .htaccess file):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ message.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

For each subdomain and make the message.php say the message.

I am not good at .htaccess but it might work.

This code would **dissable the subdomain** during the time you use it tho, so make sure you cange it back.